# Nested Loops in Python Storing Results in a singular Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops, bioinformatics

Good evening SO,

I am currently working on a program to learn more about Python as I continue my Undergraduate degree. I am attempting to creating a Bioinformatic program that takes advantage of Markov models to provide and predict certain P(x) statements throughout. I am working on cleaning up my code as I have found a TON of repeats. I am NOT asking for an answer - Moreso advice or perhaps a nudge in a direction to keep me going forward in a positive and Python centric mindset.

Is there any way in Python that I can turn

```
aa_count = markov_data_set.count('AA')
at_count = markov_data_set.count('AT')
ag_count = markov_data_set.count('AG')
ac_count = markov_data_set.count('AC')
tt_count = markov_data_set.count('TT')
ta_count = markov_data_set.count('TA')
tg_count = markov_data_set.count('TG')
tc_count = markov_data_set.count('TC')
cc_count = markov_data_set.count('CC')
ca_count = markov_data_set.count('CA')
cg_count = markov_data_set.count('CG')
ct_count = markov_data_set.count('CT')
gg_count = markov_data_set.count('GG')
ga_count = markov_data_set.count('GA')
gt_count = markov_data_set.count('GT')
gc_count = markov_data_set.count('GC')
```

Into something more Simple? I've been reading several books on Python (Crashcourse on Python and Primers to Scientific Coding with Python) and I believe I can use loops or nested loops to make something shorter and more organized. Examples I have tried are as follows:

```
di_nucleotide = ('AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TT', 'TA', 'TG', 'TC', 'CC', 'CA', 'CG', 'CT', 'GG', 'GA', 'GT', 'GC')
nucleotide_count = ()
nucleotide_frequency = []

for binomials in di_nucleotide:
     di_nucleotide.count()
```

The problem is, sadly... I get stuck from there, which is a bit discouraging. What I would want the end product to be would be is something that stores Var1 and Var2 into a singular dictionary file I can store or call later while also having those two variables separate as needed.

```
di_nucleotide = ('AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TT', 'TA', 'TG', 'TC', 'CC', 'CA', 'CG', 'CT', 'GG', 'GA', 'GT', 'GC')
nucleotide_count = (int1, int2, int3, int4, ...)
nucleotide_frequency = ['AA':Count, 'AT'Count, 'AG'Count, ...]
```

This will be my first post on SO. I recognize this may not be the best avenue to ask for advice, but if there is anything I can do to make my posts better in the future, please let me know so I may improve.

As always, thank you, everyone, and have an amazing day! I look forward to continuing my journey on coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` to generate the pairs:

```
import itertools

bases = 'ACGT'
nucs = [''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(bases, repeat=2)]
# ['AA', 'AC', 'AG' ....
```

You can then run the function in a loop inside a dictionary comprehension, replacing your individual calls:

```
counts = {nuc: markov_data_set.count(nuc) for nuc in nucs}
```

`counts` is a dictionary of your results. The keys are `'AA'`, `'AC'` and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Jan, it really means a lot to see how to tackles this in more than one way. 

Just to make sure I'm understanding this string... we assume the bases will obviously be ACGT. By using the nucs process we are asking to join each item into a separate list which can be then called to count. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @BountifulDawn The first part constructs the pair names 'AA', 'AC' and the so on from the basic names, by taking the 'cartesian product' of the characters, i.e. generating all possible length=2 pairs. Remember that iterating over a string will give you the characters. The second part just calls `markov_data_set.count for each name in that list, and assigns the result as a value to the key representing the pair.

Comment: Wonderfully informative. Thanks again! I will keep working! This community is so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can store everything in a dictionary, which you generate on the fly:

```
# initialise dictionary and total counts
nucleotide_counts = {}
total_counts = 0

# loop through dinucleotide counts
for dn in ['AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TT', 'TA', 'TG', 'TC', 'CC', 'CA', 'CG', 'CT', 'GG', 'GA', 'GT', 'GC']:
    # store in dictionary
    counts = markov_data_set.count(dn)
    nucleotide_counts[dn] = counts
    total_counts += counts
```

from there, you can generate the frequencies:

```
frequencies = {}
for dn, counts in nucleotide_counts.items():
    frequencies[dn] = counts / total_counts
```

Comment: This looks amazingly more simple than what I thought it was. If I'm reading this correctly, dn is just a way to call on all items from the di_nucleotide list. Once this call occurs we are simply adding this count into the initial call. Am I correct? 

Thank you so much for such a prompt response.

Comment: Essentially, yes. You have a list of strings (in your case these are dinucleotides). You go through each element of your list, and use it to 1. count the occurences in in your dataset, and 2. create a dictionary entry, to which you assign the counts. You can call the individual entries (e.g. for `'AA'` with `nucleotide_counts['AA']`)

Comment: One thing I do notice that I'm having a hard time grasping is the 8th line of code...

`counts = markov_dataset.count(dn)`

It seems to spit up an error that markov_dataset isn't defined... Do I need to define this var before use?

Comment: hm, try `markov_data_set` instead? So the way that you asked your question implies that you have something that is called `markov_data_set`, on which you can call `.count'. Doing this returns a number, which you assign to the appropriate entry of your dictionary.

Comment: @BountifulDawn Please upvote answers that helped you and mark the answer that solved your problem. This improves the motivation for all those involved.

Comment: Hey @Sammy, I certainly will do that. I wasn't by a computer for the time being as I was asleep. Once i run through the answers on something a little more user friendly i will be happy to update. Also, I've placed votes but it tells me since I have less than 15 reputation, (I made the act yesterday) I cannot see those votes. I hope this helps.